# Anglular gives access denied to mymodal.html

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller where I define a function along with it's template. It is a modal that needs to pop-up. No modal pops up and access denied for mymodal.html.

My controller/app:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl',function (
...
...
...
$scope.removeComment = function (reply) {
  var myModalInstance = $modal.open({
    scope: $scope,
    templateUrl: 'mymodal.html',
    controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, reply) {
```

in the template I am including:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller='MyCtrl'>
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: syntax error after `controller('MyCtrl'`

Comment: Copy paste error, I updated

Comment: is the path of modal.html correct?

Comment: Are you running this from a server or directly from file?

Comment: Yes the path is correct. The same path works for a similar modal, even without the myApp and MyCtrl in the template. @RickardStaaf backend is on Server and html on frontend, both locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is in your `controller` function: `reply` is not defined, i suppose. If you will open console, i think you will see something like this:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: replyProvider <- reply
```

If you want to inject something into your controller, you can write some service.

BTW, if you are going to use some minificator you will see errors, because when you define `controller` by this way and minificate your code - your injections will be minificated too.

Better way is to do something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', function ($scope, $modal) {
  $scope.removeComment = function (reply) {
    var myModalInstance = $modal.open({
      scope: $scope,
      templateUrl: 'mymodal.html',
      controller: 'modalController',
      ...
      });
    };
/* SOME CODE HERE */
}]);
```

and

```
app.controller('modalController', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
  /* SOME LOGIC HERE */
}]);
```